# ; or , in calculated columns

Tags: 2007, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, regional-settings

The separator is related to the language settings.

Rule of thumb: of the decimal separator is a . (dot) then the parameter separator is a , (comma)

So most non-english languages have the , (comma) as decimal separator and need the ; (semi-colon) as parameter separator

Comment: When you say TEXT=([Date], "mmmm"), you are actually referring to: =TEXT([Date],"mmmm"), no? I would recommend to try the formulas in MS Excel first, for me is easier to debug than using SP itself.

Comment: Yes sorry, I will edit the question. It's just the regional settings difference that blow my mind. Is it ',' in EU and ';' in US or something like that?

Comment: As far as I know it is "," everywhere. This [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2) may help with the formulas.